Is a quasi-projective variety $X$ projective if every closed proper subset is projective?
It is well known that if a variety is projective, then every proper closed subset is also projective. I am curious as to weather or not the converse is true.
Here "variety" means quasi-projective variety.

If "every closed subset" really means every closed subset (i.e. including $X$), then yes - is that what you intend?

@KReiser edited

No, this is not true. Let $X=\Bbb A^1$; then every proper closed subset is a finite set of points which is projective via the standard embedding $\Bbb A^1\to\Bbb P^1$.
If you require that $\dim X > 1$, then the answer is yes. Write $X=\overline{X}\setminus Y$ for $\overline{X},Y\subset\Bbb P^n$ projective varieties with $Y\subset\overline{X}$. Let $H$ be a hypersurface intersecting both $Y$ and $X$ but not containing $X$ nor $Y$. Then $H\cap X=(H\cap \overline{X})\setminus (H\cap Y)$, which is a closed subset of $X$ but not a closed subset of $\Bbb P^n$: any irreducible component of $H\cap \overline{X}$ must be of dimension at least 1, and any irreducible component of $H\cap Y$ must be of strictly smaller dimension. But no projective variety of dimension $\geq 1$ minus a subset of strictly smaller dimension is projective. (Basically, the only way to cheat this that a finite set of points minus a finite set of points can be projective.)
